# Trouble defining user inputs in functions

Tags: python, azure, jupyter

I'm following the Microsoft introduction to Python course for beginners on edX, I'm having trouble in their second module where they ask you to create function that adds the "Doctor" title to a user inputted name.

This is the advice they provide:

- Define function make_doctor()  that takes a parameter name
- get user input for variable full_name
- call the function using full_name   as argument
- print the return value
- create and call make_doctor() with full_name argument from user input - then print the return value

This is what I have so far:

```
def make_doctor(name):
full_name = print("Doctor" + input().title())
return full_name

print(name)
```

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is an [off-side rule language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule#Off-side_rule_languages):

> ### Python Reference Manual ([link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html))
>
> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
> line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
> turn is used to determine the grouping of statements.

In contrast to others such as curly-bracket languages, indentation is (*generally*) not stylistic, but required in order to group statements. Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
def make_doctor(name):
    return "Doctor" + name


full_name = input()
print(make_doctor(full_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_doctor(name):
    # add the Doctor title to the name parameter
    d_name = 'Doctor '+name
    # print the return value
    print(d_name)
    return d_name

# get the user input for the variable full_name
full_name=input('Enter your full name: ')
# pass full_name as an argument to make_doctor function
doc = make_doctor(full_name)
# print return value
print(doc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    def make_doctor(name):
        full_name = input()
    return full_name

    print('Doctor ' + full_name)
```

Comment: the indentation of the line with `return full_name` is not correct, should be aligned with the previous line.